# How do I link a single table to data in two different tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm running for office and have created a web app for tracking my door knocks to voters at their homes. The database contains a table called `voters` that contains all the necessary information about voters in my community.

I'd like to add a new feature to track donors to my campaign. Not all of these donors live in the community and do not vote in the district where I'm running for office. I do not need to track the same kind of info for these individuals as I do for the voters so I'm going to place these individuals into a table called `nonvoters.`

Now, the individuals in my "voters" table can also make donations, and I want to track those as well.

To track the donations from both voters and nonvoters, I'd like to set up a new table called "donations." This table would contain the appropriate details about the donation.

But I'm uncertain as to what the best structure is for linking the `donations` table to the "voters" and "nonvoters" table. If I create a column called `voter_id` in the table to key it to the donors information, there's no way to know which table that ID refers to. So do I set up two columns, `nonvoter_id` and `voter_id` and insert the ID into the applicable column depending on whether the donor is a voter? This seems weird.

Or maybe I create a column in both the `voters` and `nonvoters` table called `donor_id` that I can use to link my data in the donations table. If I went this route, it seems like I'd have to do a some behind the scenes work to ensure the donor_id was unique and was keyed to the data inside the donations table.

Or maybe there are other approaches I'm not familiar with. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single table for voters and non-voters, let's say persons. You can have a flag in the persons table that indicates if the person is a voter or you may even derive this from their address (if that's possible).

I would create a donations table and link each donation to a person (or persons) in the persons table using the id in the persons table. If a donation can be given by multiple people, then you will need a 3rd connection table with person id and donation id as 2 fields. These 2 fields would be the primary key for the connection table.

Comment: Thanks. I was initially going to do that but the current voters table has a state_id field that has to be unique and I don't have that information for nonvoters. But perhaps the biggest reason I don't want to do this is it doesn't quite feel right to store two different entities in the same table.  It seems like it would cause problems later on down the road.

Comment: I do not see them as different entities: they are persons. I do not know what that state_id is, but in mysql if you put a unique index on a column, then you can still have multiple rows with null values (non voters), unless you use BDB table engine. You can also consider putting only those fields to separate voters table, that are extra for voters. This depends on the number of extra columns a voter would have in comparison with a non-voter.

Comment: This way your donations are still linked to a single persons table.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that about the unique index. Good to know. Thank you.

In thinking this over some more, though, I realize that I will also have to track donations from organizations. Organizations are not people.

So even if I do place voter and nonvoters into the same table, I'm going to run into the same problem of listing donations from both people and organizations.